# MultiResourceItemReader what happened if Job fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Spring Batch has MultiResourceItemReader to process set of files
i want to know that what happens if job fails

for ex if there 10 files to read and skip limit is 20. suppose 5 files already processed and while reading 6th file if skip limit exceeds 20 during the reading of file then it will skip that file only and move to next file or whole job will be failed ?.

i want to know skip limit is used for each file its read or whole set of files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skips are at an item level across the entire step, not individual files.  So if you process 5 files out of 10, then hit the skip limit at line 20 out of 100 in file 6, the job will fail and can be restarted  at the point of rollback (where the chunk that contained the final failure began).  You can read more about the skip logic in Spring Batch in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#configuringSkip

Comment: thanks Michael. so if the job is restarted from the chunk where the final failure began. Is the skip count again starts from 0 until it reach to 20 to fail job again ?

Comment: The skip count should be reset on a restart.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the answer